# When using a lookup column in SharePoint Online, can you edit in both directions?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Can you edit the master list by updating the linked field, or must you always edit the master list and have the data cascade down?

For example, if the master list has "Clients" but is maintained by someone else and I find an error, can I update my lookup column "Clients" in my list and have it update the master list as well? Or does the data only go one way?

(Sorry, new at this! thanks!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data in a lookup column connection only goes one way. The field values are being pulled from the master list to display in the lookup column(s) on the child list.

There is the option of adding on the master list another lookup column that connects to the corresponding lookup column on the child list, but this will just give you the count of related items in the child list.